# fetching data from php Admin for display

Tags: php, html

I have a total 4 book of abc. I showing that author 1 book in book detail page. As well as i want to display remaining 3 books of author in below other books by this writer section. But in this section showing 1 book of that author. Please help me what can i do?

Book detail code:

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_GET['pid']) && !empty($_GET['pid'])){
        $id = $_GET['pid'];

        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM bookrecord WHERE id ='$id' and status='a'");

        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            $imgData = $result->fetch_assoc();
            extract($imgData);
                ?>
                    <div class="preview-pic tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="pic-1">                        
                            <img src="admin_pannel/book_images/<?php echo $imgData['file']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

OTHER BOOKS BY THIS WRITER code:

```
<?php                           
    if(isset($_GET['auth_name']) && !empty($_GET['auth_name'])){
        $auth_name = $_GET['auth_name'];
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM bookrecord WHERE author_name ='$auth_name' and status='a'");

        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            extract($row);  
                ?>  
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <img src="admin_pannel/book_images/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>" class="img-responsive center-block">
                        <h4 class="text-center"><?php echo $row['book_title']; ?></h4>
                        <h5 class="text-center"><?php echo $row['author_name']; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                <?php
        }
    }   
?>
```

This is my (book-detail.php) page and i come from this link:

```
<a class="btnpoem" href="book-detail.php?pid=<?php echo htmlentities($row['id']);?>&auth_name=<?php echo htmlentities($row['author_name']);?>">Download</a>
```

Comment: both code is on the same page?

Comment: Yes, both code in same page.

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `while()` in your second code:-

```
<?php                           
    if(isset($_GET['auth_name']) && !empty($_GET['auth_name'])){
        $auth_name = $_GET['auth_name'];
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM bookrecord WHERE author_name ='$auth_name' and status='a'");

        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                extract($row);  
?>  
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img src="admin_pannel/book_images/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>" class="img-responsive center-block">
                    <h4 class="text-center"><?php echo $row['book_title']; ?></h4>
                    <h5 class="text-center"><?php echo $row['author_name']; ?></h5>
                </div>
<?php
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

***Note:-*** Your queries are ***`Wide-Open`*** for ***`SQL-INJECTION`***. 
 So try to use ***`prepared statements`***.

***Reference:-***

[PHP: mysqli::prepare - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PHP: PDO::prepare - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: @MilindBhuvad  glad to help you :):)

Comment: Ok Sir, Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code from this code and in this code you have to change your sql query a lil bit to get rows except first one because you have got first row(Image), and instead of while loop you can also use foreach

```
   <?php                           
        if(isset($_GET['auth_name']) && !empty($_GET['auth_name'])){
            $auth_name = $_GET['auth_name'];
            $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM bookrecord WHERE author_name ='$auth_name' and status='a'" and WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM your_table GROUP BY USER_ID));

            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                foreach ($result as $key){ 
    ?>  
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <img src="admin_pannel/book_images/<?php echo $key['file']; ?>" class="img-responsive center-block">
                        <h4 class="text-center"><?php echo $key['book_title']; ?></h4>
                        <h5 class="text-center"><?php echo $key['author_name']; ?></h5>
                    </div>
    <?php
                }
            }
        }
    ?>`
```